# OpenGL snapshot changes color

Tags: ios, opengl-es, uiimage, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I draw a figure on CAEAGLLayer

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES);
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR);

glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

It looks like this: [src image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/khf07kwzdrrcapg/1.png)

After I took this picture context this code:

```
- (UIImage*)snapshot:(UIView*)eaglview
{

GLint backingWidth, backingHeight;

// Bind the color renderbuffer used to render the OpenGL ES view
// If your application only creates a single color renderbuffer which is already bound at this point,
// this call is redundant, but it is needed if you're dealing with multiple renderbuffers.
// Note, replace "_colorRenderbuffer" with the actual name of the renderbuffer object defined in your class.
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, _colorRenderbuffer);

// Get the size of the backing CAEAGLLayer
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

NSInteger x = 0, y = 0, width = backingWidth, height = backingHeight;
NSInteger dataLength = width * height * 4;
GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(GLubyte));

// Read pixel data from the framebuffer
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

// Create a CGImage with the pixel data
// If your OpenGL ES content is opaque, use kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast to ignore the alpha channel
// otherwise, use kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataLength, NULL);
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast,
                                ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
```

аnd getting here is distortion in color: [dst image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w0jiveyjvazyptr/2.png).

What could be the problem?

Comment: after the image is resized, stretched almost any artifacts appeared as white rectangles [dst image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2f4z7cbbwpzrsyu/result.png)

Comment: Can you post the image you are expecting? Anyway if the content display is correct but the image itself is not it is most likely the error is in creating the image from data. kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast might be the problem as your intent is most likely to ignore the alpha channel.

Comment: I want to get like [that](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8s0xeyzjdmwf6vm/bad_rez.png), only a white background should be transparent. That is simply superimposed on the figure background.

Comment: So how about trying kCGImageAlphaLast. That premultiplied has no sense at all.

Comment: I replaced kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast with kCGImageAlphaLast in 'CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,
                                    ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);' figure and the image on the background of markups disappeared ..

Answer (score 0):

If I change

`glClearColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);`

on

`glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);`

screenshot context is obtained without color distortion. Only the color of a shape other. [dst image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1nltzgog4b3j3lo/badrez2.png)

```
glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES);
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR);

//glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glViewport(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

glUseProgram(programHandle);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your blend equation is wrong - is this better?

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```